# I got exception when connecting to TFS sources in Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

I cannot get sources dialog in my visual studio 2012. 
I got null reference exception: Any ideas what causes this?

[image]

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.PendingChanges.PendingChangesModelVS.Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, VersionControlServer versionControlServer, Workspace workspace)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.PendingChanges.PendingChangesPage.InitializeModel(PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerPageBase.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.PendingChanges.PendingChangesPageVS.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerPageHost.Initialize(TeamExplorerPageContext context)
```

VS pro with latest updates.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had this error too, might be the same cause, but check your file:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml

Mine contained the message:

The cache file C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache\VersionControl.config is not valid and cannot be loaded.
Please correct or delete the file.

I renamed the file (rather than deleting it).
I then started visual studio with the /resetSkipPkgs switch and it is working again now.

Best of luck and I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

DNS-client service was stopped.